# In the TCP Header, why is the Urgent pointer 16 bits long when it points to a sequence number of 32 bits

Tags: tcp, header

In the TCP Header, why is the Urgent pointer field 16 bits long when it points to a sequence number of 32 bits

Comment: Presumably because if you need to go back more than 64k segments, it's no longer urgent.

Comment: But aren't larger values for sequence numbers the more recent ones?

Comment: The urgent field is an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as pointing to a sequence number.  It's true that the sequence numbers are used to count the total number of bytes transferred, that they are 32 bits in length, and that they can wrap around; the Urgent pointer, however, is a pointer into the data.

The urgent pointer indicates the offset from the sequence number of the *received TCP segment with the urgent bit set*.  Therefore, it's not necessary for it to represent a 32 bit number, but it also means that the urgent data must be within the 64k following that sequence number.